# On tests for correlation in case of bivariate observations

Tags: regression, correlation, bivariate

We have bivariate observations {($X_i, Y_i$), i=1,2,...n}. We are interested in testing if they are uncorrelated. One test is based on $r$ (correlation coefficient): $r\sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}}\sim t_{n-2}$. Another is based on fitting a regression model $Y_i = a+b X_i+e_i$ and testing for b=0. Are both the tests identical? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: Both those tests are based on regression and should be equivalent.